# Text Animations - Range Selector Not Moving - After Effects

Tags: after-effects, animation, adobe

I am trying to animate the position of my text to create a text animation ([as seen here](https://youtu.be/b1_p2qQf_Ts?t=282)) and I have followed these exact steps:

1. Created a text layer Clicked "animate" and chose "position"
2. Renamed my Range Selector to "initial position"
3. Added a keyframe with the End set to 100
4. Moved forward a few frames
5. Added another keyframe with the End set to 0

When I play the animation, nothing is happening. The text remains on screen without any movement.

What am I missing? I followed the YouTube tutorial step-by-step so I'm lost as to why it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you adjusted the Transform Position, to make the letters move downwards? The Range Selector only tells AE which letters you want to affect. The transform position tells it how far and which way you want the lettters to move.